# Missing co-ordinates in highcharts heatmap show empty box

Tags: javascript, highcharts, heatmap

I am trying out [heatmap](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/heatmap) from Highcharts and just ran into a problem. In my case, I am getting blank cells in case if there is no data in series data for those co-ordinates but in case if co-ordinates are present but data itself is null then it shows an empty cell.

Eg. - https://jsfiddle.net/1ys23cte/1/

For [1,4,null] it shows empty cell but for [0,4] and [4,4] it shows blank.

```
series: [{
        name: 'Sales per employee',
        borderWidth: 1,
        data: [[0, 0, 10], [0, 1, 19], [0, 2, 8], [0, 3, 24], [1, 0, 92], [1, 1, 58], [1, 2, 78], [1, 3, 117], [1, 4, null], [2, 0, 35], [2, 1, 15], [2, 2, 123], [2, 3, 64], [2, 4, 52], [3, 0, 72], [3, 1, 132], [3, 2, 114], [3, 3, 19], [3, 4, 16], [4, 0, 38], [4, 1, 5], [4, 2, 8], [4, 3, 117], [5, 0, 88], [5, 1, 32], [5, 2, 12], [5, 3, 6], [5, 4, 120], [6, 0, 13], [6, 1, 44], [6, 2, 88], [6, 3, 98], [6, 4, 96], [7, 0, 31], [7, 1, 1], [7, 2, 82], [7, 3, 32], [7, 4, 30], [8, 0, 85], [8, 1, 97], [8, 2, 123], [8, 3, 64], [8, 4, 84], [9, 0, 47], [9, 1, 114], [9, 2, 31], [9, 3, 48], [9, 4, 91]],
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            color: '#000000'
        }
    }]
```

I wanted to know, is it possible to just show empty cells in case of missing data too?

Thanks

Comment: Here you can find how the `heatmap` data structure should look like: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.heatmap.data, as you can see the three values are required - if you set just two in the array the point is not rendered, so if you want to render empty cells you should add a `null`

Comment: Hi @SebastianWędzel thanks for such a quick response. I understand what you are saying but what I meant was as you can see there are no elements in series.data for co-ordinates (0,4) and (4,4) positions and it shows blank there. I need to show empty cells there :).

Comment: Pratik Ahire, Is this an output which you wanted to achieve? https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/170zx9dc/ if yes so, you need to render those points as the null value, just like I mentioned in the previous comment.